# How do I suppress Zenity dialog pop-up when starting Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: zenity, jupyter

When I launch Jupyter Notebook from terminal, a Zenity notification window pops-up saying:

> Allow opening file?
>   Allow snap "jupyter" to open file "/run/user/1000/snap.jupyter/jupyter/nbserver-5664-open.html"?
>   YES/NO

If I click on YES, Jupyter appears in a new browser tab.

This is the first time ever I get asked for confirmation to open Jupyter. I'd like to skip the annoying Zenity question. How can I do so?

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Please file a bug report with whomever the author of the Snap is.

Answer (score 1):

Problem found. I had installed jupyter with snap. Uninstalled and reinstalled with pip, now it works as expected.